# What is the CIDR notation for all IPv4 addresses?

Tags: networking

For example, the CIDR notation for the IPv4 block `192.168.100.0/22` represents the 1024 IPv4 addresses from `192.168.100.0` to `192.168.103.255`.

I'm in an environment where everything is blocked by default, so need to open up the full IPv4-address space on port 443 to give the world access through https.

What is the CIDR notation for all IPv4 addresses?

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. I need this for a firewall rule @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: How about `*`? If not working, `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: you are willing to open your firewall for all addresses? What you need firewall then for?

Comment: Yes @MarcinOrlowski! I'm in an environment where everything is blocked by default, so need to open up the full IPv4-address space on port 443 to give the world access through https.

Comment: That's right @HansPetterTaugbølKragset! Thanks, mind adding it as an answer so I can give you the credit for it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The so called [default route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route) is `0.0.0.0/0` and matches any IPv4 address.